# Testing a React component that uses redux toolkit and RTKQuery

Tags: jestjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have been making an app using redux toolkit and RTKQuery, and hit a stumbling block on how to test a component that uses slices:

**Component**

```
export const Status = () => {
  const selectedKidId = useSelector(getSelectedKidId);

  const { selectedKid } = useGetKidsQuery(undefined, {
    selectFromResult: ({ data }) => ({
      selectedKid: data?.find((kid: KidType) => kid.id === selectedKidId),
    }),
  });
  return (
    <section>
      <p>
        Active:{' '}
        {selectedKidId !== null ? selectedKid?.firstName : 'Select a kid'}
      </p>
    </section>
  );
};
```

**Test**

```
test('title renders as expected', () => {
  renderWithProviders(<Status />, {
    preloadedState: { kids: { selectedKidId: '0' } },
  });

  expect(screen.getByText(/Monsters!/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

As you see I can add a `selectedKidId` in the `preloadedState` but the component also uses a generated hook `useGetKidsQuery` which return a list of kids, I don't know how or if I can add this to `preloadedState` as its an apiSlice.

How would I get my list of kids data into this test?

Comment: Did you solve? I have exactly same issue...

Comment: Can you please provide a codesanbox link? @Neil